# how to use chartJS to show breakdown of selected data

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

I am using chartJS in  php Laravel framework  project, with data being sent from an sql stored procedure. I want to be able to click through the data being presented in a chartjs to show a breakdown of the specific records clicked on.
For example, if i have a bar chart which shows that 6 calls were missed on monday, and 4 were missed on tuesday, I want to be able to click mondays bar chart and show the breakdown of those missed calls.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>missed Call?</th>
    <th>Reason?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>1</th>
    <td>01/12/2020</td>
    <td>yes</td>
    <td>"no one at phone"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>2</th>
    <td>01/12/2020</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>3</th>
    <td>01/12/2020</td>
    <td>yes</td>
    <td>"no one at phone"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>4</th>
    <td>01/12/2020</td>
    <td>yes</td>
    <td>"no one at phone"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>5</th>
    <td>04/12/2020</td>
    <td>yes</td>
    <td>"no one at phone"</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <th>6</th>
    <td>04/12/2020</td>
    <td>yes</td>
    <td>"lines down"</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <th>7</th>
    <td>04/12/2020</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>"n/a"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the chart:

```
var data = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [3, 2],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "01/12/2020 missed calls",
    "04/12/2020 missed calls",
  ]
};

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: data
    });

    canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
      var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
      if (activePoints[0]) {
        var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
        var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

        var label = chartData.labels[idx];
        var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];

        var url = "https://jsfiddle.net/nikk96/z72p9n03/14/";
        console.log(url);
        window.open(url);
      }
    };
  }
);
```

as you can see I have a table that has columns: `id, date   ,missed Call?,Reason?`

I want to click on the data and get everything in the columns for the date clicked.  Currently the onclick event opens a new window that shows a table, this table needs to be populated with whatever data would be there for the date chosen.

[Heres a link of the example](https://jsfiddle.net/nikk96/z72p9n03/15/)

Comment: Your question is too vague. Stack Overflow is for specific questions. If you're problem is that you're not sure how to make a link on a specific bar in a chartJS graph, that could be an excellent question, but first make some sample of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to need to do is store two arrays in memory.

1. That contains the data to make the chart that is ingested by ChartJS
2. That contains the other meta data you want to display in a table.

The most important thing is that these lists have the same order that way the index of the active point matches the one with the meta data.